# Func variance with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, covariance, func

Tried to something like this in our code but it fails:

```
Func<Employee, Employee> _myFunc;

void Main()
{
    Func<Employee, Employee> test1  = _myFunc;//Ok
    Func<Employee, Person> test2  = _myFunc;//Ok
    Func<Person, Employee> test3 = _myFunc;//Fails
    Func<Person, Person> test4  = _myFunc;//Fails
}

public class Person { }
public class Employee : Person { }
```

The last two cases give this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Func<Employee, Employee>` to `System.Func<Person, Employee>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any idea why?

Comment: Because the return type (the last generic parameter of `Func<>`) is covariant, while the input parameters (all the other generic parameters of `Func<>`) are contravariant.

Comment: Fun fact: conversions of *method groups* to delegates are also covariant and contravariant in the same way.  If you have `Giraffe M(Animal a)` and `delegate Animal D(Tiger t)` then `D d = M;` is legal in C#, even though D is not even generic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the signature for `Func<T, TResult>`, you'll see that the input parameters (`T` in this case) are *contravariant*, and the return type (`TResult`) is *covariant*

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

Contravariance is basically about being able to pass a "bigger" type to a method expecting a "smaller" type, where covariance is exactly the opposite.

Eric Lippert puts this [beautifully and elegantly (emphasis mine)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/30/whats-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility/):

> A generic type I is **covariant** (in T) if construction with reference
>   type arguments **preserves the direction of assignment compatibility**. It
>   is **contravariant** (in T) if it **reverses the direction of assignment
>   compatibility**. And it is **invariant** if it **does neither**. And by that, we
>   simply are saying in a concise way that the projection which takes a T
>   and produces I is a covariant/contravariant/invariant projection.

Comment: There's a typo in Lippert's original post. It should be `out T` for covariant.

Comment: @haim770 I don't think that's what Eric meant. I'm assuming he meant that the generic type `I<T>` is covariant/contravariant *in T*, meaning for every `T`.

Comment: Yes. I read the full article and now I can realize what he meant. Thanks

Comment: That is what I meant but I agree it is very confusing the way I wrote it! Regrettably I no longer have write access to msdn blogs.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Func<T, TResult>` is a defined as

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

As you can see, the second parameter (`TResult`) is indeed a covariant, but the first parameter (`T`, which is the input of the function) is actually a contravariant (you can only feed it with something that is less-derived).

`Func<Employee, Person>` is fine because it sill matches the signature, while `Func<Person, Person>` fails because it isn't.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand it now:

```
void Main()
{
    Func<Employee, Employee> getEmployeesBoss = (Employee employee) => {return employee.Boss;};
    //This works as it expects a Person to be returned and employee.Boss is a person.
    Func<Employee, Person> getEmployeesBoss1 = getEmployeesBoss;
    //This fails as I could pass a non Employee person to this func which would not work.
    Func<Person, Employee> getEmployeesBoss2 = getEmployeesBoss;
}

class Person {} 
class Employee : Person { public Employee Boss{get;set;}    }
```

Answer (score -3):

A `Person` is not an `Employee`

There is no cast possible between `Func<Employee, xxx>` and `Func<Person, xxx>`