# Pass Func<IList, int> to a method taking Func<IEnumerable, int>?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to pass a `Func<IList<object>, int>` to a method that takes a `Func<IEnumerable<object>, int>`.  Can't seem to work it out.  Is it possible to do something like below?

```
    class A {
        void Test() {
            IList<object> data = new List<object>();

            // can't pass in MyFunc, doesn't compile
            ApplyFunc(MyFunc, data);
        }

        int MyFunc(IList<object> data) {
            return 0;
        }

        void ApplyFunc(Func<IEnumerable<object>, int> f, IList<object> data) {
            f(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006997/func-variance-with-multiple-parameters/36007182 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025176/conversion-from-funcobject-string-to-funcstring-string-works-but-to-funcint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the delegate in question is defined as Func(in T, ...), you only allowed to use a less derived type. IList(T) implements IEnumerable(T) which is more derived.

(From kiziu's comment...)
[Conversion from Func<object,string> to Func<string,string> works but to Func<int,string> fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025176/conversion-from-funcobject-string-to-funcstring-string-works-but-to-funcint)

Possible solutions are to use a lambda (as described in one of the other answers) or change the signature of MyFunc

Answer (score 2):

Your *Test* method can be as follows:

```
public void Test()
{
    IList<object> data = new List<object>();

    ApplyFunc(x => MyFunc(x as IList<object>), data);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If generics are an option, you can do:

```
class A {
    void Test() {
        IList<object> data = new List<object>();

        // can't pass in MyFunc, doesn't compile
        ApplyFunc(MyFunc, data);
    }

    int MyFunc(IList<object> data) {
        return 0;
    }

    void ApplyFunc<TEnumerable>(Func<TEnumerable, int> f, TEnumerable data)
         where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<object>
    {
       f(data);
    }
}
```

See the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/juEWYf

Comment: unless i'm missing something that doesn't compile.

Comment: @CoderBrien changed it. With the delegate you would have needed a cast. Sorry, missed that.